# Problem sorting events by Term Reference

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Hi I created an Event Calendar in Drupal 7.3 I have a content type set up with term ref everything works great when i click on an event I have at the bottom display the term Ref 
you can see it here  http://www.ofmq.com/content/pain-falls-major-injury-mcalester

at the bottom of the Event there is a link to the term ref in this case it is Nursing Home
when you click it you get a list of all events that have Nursing Home as a term 
my problem is how can I sort the list generated by event start date? 
Any help would be appreciated
Cheers
DEW

Answer (score 0):

It would seem like your link is simply rendering the taxonomy term usage page (that comes standard with Drupal). What I would recommend is [creating Views with Contextual Filters](https://www.drupal.org/node/1578558) (the filter could be the name of the taxonomy term, in this case `nursing-home`).

Once you have your [Views with Contextual Filters](https://www.drupal.org/node/1578558) built (with a set link, such as /events/) then you can simply rewrite the result of the term field (i.e. display it as plain text and then rewrite) using tokens for the machine name of the term and provide it as a link.

Does this make sense?